# understanding twitter gem readme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth

I have few questions about this portion of the readme of the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/README.md)

> ```
> Client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
>   config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
>   config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
>   config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
>   config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
> end
> ```
>
> After configuration, requests can be made like so:
>
> ```
> client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
> ```

1) Where do you put the keys config block? I've seen some guides put it in a separate file, like `config/twitter_credentials.rb`, `omniauth.rb`, or `devise.rb`. If I'm using devise should all 4 keys be in the devise file?

2) when the `.update` method is called, who tweets the tweet? The app account or the logged in user consuming my site?

3) are the access tokens what allows users to tweet from their account, and not the app's account?

Code showing how to let users tweet from their own account would be appreciated, as they seem to be  missing from the readme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It doesn't really matter where you put the initializer code. But usually you put code relative to a certain gem in an initializer with the same name as the gem. So in this case, I'd put that code inside a file called `twitter.rb`. However, in this case I don't think you actually need an initializer.
2. When the update method is called, the user to whom the `access_token` and `access_token_secret` belong is the one who tweets.
3. Yes, the `access_token` is what allows users to tweet from their account. You can get that token and the corresponding secret from `omniauth-twitter`'s response.

   ```
   omniauth = env['omniauth.auth']
   user.access_token = omniauth.credentials.token
   user.access_token_secret = omniauth.credentials.secret
   user.save
   ```

   Of course, to be able to save the token and the secret you need to add the appropriate fields (`access_token` and `access_token_secret`) to your user table.

You can then tweet from a controller, like so:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"]
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV["TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"]
      config.access_token        = current_user.access_token
      config.access_token_secret = current_user.access_token_secret
    end
    client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually saw this today. `Your Access Token
This access token can be used to make API requests on your own account's behalf. Do not share your access token secret with anyone. ` So it seems #1 is correct, #2 and #3 aren't quite.

So it seems the access token is to allow others to tweet from your own app account's behalf. That would mean the consumer tokens are so that the app can tweet on behalf of logged in users.

Comment: It seems that using the update method to tweet isn't the best way to do things.

You'd have to wire up and design all the pre-tweeting page. Twitter has a share button that goes to a pre-built page that pre-populates the tweet, allows users to confirm, allows users to log into twitter if not done already, and redirects you back. Seems like it's better to use that https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet